# How to create a server DataBase ( Shared DataBase ) in connected 2 program?

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-connection

I have a C# program that should installed on different connected PCs and Microsoft SQL Server DataBase .The programs works with common Database and have queries.
So how should I program that ?

Should I install SQL Server ? or I have to make one of the programs listener to response the queries ?

Comment: By "SQL DataBase" do you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: You only have to install sqlserver on server machine and alter connection string according to it.

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan This is what in my mind. Isn't there any other and better way ? I think installing SQL server for a small program isn't so good !

Comment: You could use sql lite or microsoft access database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you have a requirement for a shared database, you need to install that somewhere that will always be available.

It doesn't have to be SQL Server, not any kind of database server - it could conceivably be a shared Access file on a file server.

There are a number of editions of SQL server, and some of them are free, if that is your concern. Alternatively, a third party could host your SQL server database for you